# how to return a result from an async function after the stream is closed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, https, stream

I'm trying to make download function which will return the promise with filename as result, but it returns 'undefined'

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async function(authToken, orderId, name, format = 'pdf'){
    let url = `https://reestr-api.ru/v1/order/download?auth_token=${authToken}&order_id=${orderId}&format=${format}`;
    https.get(url, res => {
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            let filename = path.join(process.cwd(), 'files', `${name}.${format}`);
            let file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
            file.on('close', () => {
                return filename;
            });
            res.pipe(file);
        } else return false;

    });
};
```

Comment: You have to wrap everything in a new promise

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = function(authToken, orderId, name, format = 'pdf'){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let url = `https://reestr-api.ru/v1/order/download?auth_token=${authToken}&order_id=${orderId}&format=${format}`;
        https.get(url, res => {
            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                let filename = path.join(process.cwd(), 'files', `${name}.${format}`);
                let file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
                file.on('close', () => resolve(`${name}.${format}`));
                res.pipe(file);
            } else resolve(false);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.